# File not being moved to directory PHP

Tags: php

i'm trying to get form data with php on the same page. the PHP comes before the html. everything else is posted correctly however i cant get to move the uploaded file to a directory
PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
$fileName = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$tempName = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$location = "images/";
move_uploaded_file($tempName, $location . $fileName);
}
```

Here is the image input

```
<input name="img" type="file" id="real-file" hidden="hidden" />
```

any help would be really appreicated

Comment: What are the permissions of the php file running this function, and the directory you're trying to move it to. Also, does the same user own the directory and php file? Best to check if there are any errors being thrown by turning on error reporting. You can do this by chucking `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your PHP script

Comment: I turned on error reporting as you said, Where are the errors supposed to show as I dont see any errors at all, it takes me to the page where the image is supposed to show. the src of the new image is correct however since there is no image in the directory, nothing shows on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow a user to upload a file, you must use this enctype in form tag.

`enctype='multipart/form-data`

Comment: ok weird, it did that for only one file, after no other file is being moved

Comment: do you means, you need to upload mutiple files?